# Getting Docker logs to Fluentd via SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER

Tags: logging, fluentd, google-cloud-logging, systemd-journald, docker-logs

I have docker containers which writes all logs to Journald. I have added these two flags to the docker run command

`--log-driver=journald`
`--log-opt tag="docker.test"`

When I see the logs using ***journalctl CONTAINER_NAME=test-docker***, I see the the tag clearly which I defined in *--log-opt tag="docker.{{.Name}}"*

`Mar 23 06:33:57 sethnpl025 "docker.test"[1534]: {"thread":"localhost-startStop-1","level":"INFO","loggerName":.......`

My main aim is to get these logs from journald and write them to Google Cloud logging using Fluentd. But the problem is, when I try to filter logs using the **SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER** in Fluentd I do not get anything. As I read in docker documentation (if I read it correct), setting *--log-opt tag="xxxx"* will set the **CONTAINER_TAG** and **SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER**

My Fluentd config is

```
  @type systemd
  tag test
  path /var/log/journal
  <storage>
    @type local
    persistent true
    path /var/log/fluent/journal.pos
  </storage>
  matches [{ "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER": "docker.test" }]
  read_from_head true
</source>
```

My main question here is how can I filter logs from fluentd using **SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER** or am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this [Community Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/docker-gcplogs-driver) about how to configure Google Cloud Logging Driver, seems that could be useful for you.